# Angular2 Error: SecurityError: DOM Exception 18

Tags: angular, typescript, webos, smart-tv

I'm developing an application for LG smartTV (WebOS) and using Angular2. In Chrome and Firefox, everything works fine but in TV embedded browser I have a problem. This problem reproducing only when I using HTTP module and Promises.
Please help to understand what is the reason.

Errors from console:
[errors from console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zc9eq.png)

service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { News } from "../entity/news";
import {Http, Headers, Response} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class NewsService {
  private apiUrl = 'api_url';

  constructor(private http: Http) {
  }

  getNews(): Promise<News[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.apiUrl)
        .toPromise()
        .then(response => response.json()[1].newsList as News[])
        .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
    console.error('An error occurred', error);
    return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
  }

}
```

home.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NewsService } from '../services/app.news.service';
import { News } from "../entity/news";

@Component({
    selector: 'home',
    providers: [],
    styleUrls: [ './home.style.scss' ],
    templateUrl: './home.template.html'
})
export class Home {
    news: News[];

    constructor(
        public newsService: NewsService) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.newsService.getNews()
            .then(news => this.news = news);
    }
}
```